# Dynamically choose a theme

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

NET, I recently buy a book to start by myself and try to follow the exercises.

I was aware that you can apply a theme in the  tag of a web config file by just adding "theme" property, however the following exercise was to choose a theme from a dropdownlist which I couldn't  understand very well and is simply not working for me.

Here is the master page cs code (Book's code)

```
namespace WebApplication7
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string selectedTheme = Page.Theme;
                HttpCookie preferredTheme = Request.Cookies.Get("PreferredTheme");
                if (preferredTheme != null)
                {
                    selectedTheme = preferredTheme.Value;
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedTheme))
                {
                    ListItem item = ThemeList.Items.FindByValue(selectedTheme);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        protected void Theme_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpCookie preferredTheme = new HttpCookie("PreferredTheme");
            preferredTheme.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3);
            preferredTheme.Value = ThemeList.SelectedValue;
            Response.Cookies.Add(preferredTheme);
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ThemeList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Theme_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="monochrome" >Monochrome</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="colors">Colors</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

This is an example of the book "Beginning ASP.NET 4.5.1: in C# and VB"

The book doesn't mention any missing step and to be honest I don't understand how the drop down list "indexchanged" is linked to the themes I created in the App_Themes folder. I am just assuming this is related to "Page.Theme".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably need to keep reading as the example posted does not change the current theme

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work may be of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I had to create a new Asp.net folder, then App_Code folder, create a BasePage.cs folder, right click and set that file to compile, Copy and Paste the code missing in BasePage.cs.

After apply all the inheritance from Page to BasePage in all my aspx pages and done.

Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[The book](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=7TkKAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT404&lpg=PT404&dq=HttpCookie%20preferredTheme%20%3D%20Request.Cookies.Get(%22PreferredTheme%22);&source=bl&ots=_ONFiPspdA&sig=YYEO69W2ODVrhIchTdJ9VY4Gqks&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjGzLmA3MLVAhWCoJQKHSZqA7UQ6AEIMjAC#v=onepage&q=HttpCookie%20preferredTheme%20%3D%20Request.Cookies.Get(%22PreferredTheme%22)%3B&f=false) includes this code:

[image: set the theme]

to set the theme.

*I suspect you should read the entire chapter, you need to do all of it to make it work.* You can also read the [entire source code](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Beginning-ASP-NET-4-5-1-in-C-and-VB.productCd-111884677X,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) (to compare with yours).